# How to get xen server memory, disk, network and CPU information using golang?

Tags: go

how to get xen server memory, disk, network and cpu informations using golang?

Is there any packages available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it different from other servers? If not - there a a bunch of Go packages to do it, I am using this one - https://github.com/c9s/goprocinfo

Comment: This can be used for getting VM information. We cannot get xenserver information. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
xl info | grep "total_memory"
```

which gives you your host memory in KB.